# Should I use an apostrophe in ordinals?

Tags: punctuation, ordinals

> John Smith was born in Netherlands, on the 21'st of May 1981.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you would normally write "on 21 May" or "on the 21st of May" (both read aloud as "on the twenty first of May"). There's no need for an apostrophe after the number.